# Subtracting two lists together, if value is negative, take the value from the first list (Python)

Tags: python

For example, there are 2 lists.

```
list_1= [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [2, 0, 4]
```

Simple subtraction of the two lists using operator.sub would return:

```
list_3 = [-1, 2, -1]
```

I would like to return another list_4:

```
list_4 = [1, 0, 3]
```

What list_4 means essentially is that if the result of list_3 is negative, I would take the value of list_1. If the result of list_3 is positive, I would take the value of list_2.

Therefore list_4 should return 1 (from list_1), 0 (from list_2) and 3 (from list_1) respectively.

I understand this probably has something to do with list comprehension, but I can't seem to figure it out myself. Would appreciate any help that I can get!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

list comprehension:

```
[x if x < y else y for x,y in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

Result:

```
[1, 0, 3]
```

Alternatives:

- `[min(x,y) for x,y in zip(list_1, list_2)]`
- `[min(*e) for e in zip(list_1, list_2)]`
- `import numpy as np`
  `np.minimum(list_1, list_2).tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

probably this isn't the most pythonic way. I am assuming zero is positive.

```
list_4 = []
for i, element in enumerate(list_3):
   if element < 0:
      list_4.append(list_1[i])
   else: # element >= 0
      list_4.append(list_2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work for you:

```
list_4 = []
for i, num in enumerate(list_3):
    list_4.append(list_1[i] if element < 0 else list_2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension..

```
list_4 = [i if k<0 else j for i,j,k in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)]
```